# Magento MySQL Database Backup - will restore wipe everything?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I upgraded my Magento installation a couple of days ago. I have since noticed that a lot of the items in the database have vanished. Before I did the update I backed up the database. Since then I've added a few new products to the database.

**Question:** If I restore the MySQL database using cpanel, will this erase everything? or will it only override what was previously there? so the last 24hrs will still be visible and not wiped?

Hope that makes sense and someone can help!

Thanks.

Comment: Is the backup file just a .sql file?

Comment: Hi, it's a .sql.gz file.

Comment: If you decompress that, is it just SQL commands?

Comment: yeah, once opened it's just an .sql file.

Comment: Ok, are you using auto increment on any of the tables you are restoring?

Comment: Sorry, not the most technical. Before updating magento I went into cpanel and selected "Download a MySQL Database Backup" it then gave me the compressed sql file. I then noticed that for some reason a lot of my entries have for some reason vanished from the database after the upgrade. So not sure if I click in cpanel on "Restore a MySQL Database Backup" whether it will bring back the missing entries and also leave the newest ones? The older ones are obviously the most important. The last 24hrs I could input again if need be. Hope that makes sense? Really not sure what to do, bit of a disaster.

Comment: Do you have direct access to the MySQL database?

Comment: I have the backup compressed .sql file in a dropbox folder.

Comment: I meant the actual MySQL database in the server, not the SQL file

Comment: I have access to cpanel where I can restore it? or phpmyadmin? but I don't know much about using phpmyadmin so I'm a bit worried about breaking anything further.

Comment: Yup, I was referring to PHPMyAdmin or any other access tool. As long as you don't edit any of the structures you should be fine. Can you go into PHPMyAdmin and click the database name, then click structure next to the table name and see if any of the rows say Auto Increment?

Comment: Doesn't appear so? When I click the database name and then click structure at the top it displays a list of tables. I can't see anything sayin auto increment.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rw7y1uatb3lnd36/screen-php.png?dl=0

Comment: Hm, I wasn't expecting you to have that many tables. I see that it includes inventory. Are the items you add to the database given an id number?

Comment: Yeah, all entries have a column called ID

Comment: Are those automatically generated (ie everyone is 1 higher than the previous) or do you enter them?

Comment: They're automatically generated.

Comment: Ok, do you happen to know the ID of one of the items that disappeared?

Comment: Yeah, I should do. For example. I rarely delete any. I just searched for ID's between 1200 and 1300 and it only returned 41 records. Therefore there are over 50 records missing between 1200 and 1300.

Comment: Ok, can you open the SQL file in a text editor and tell me if you find any TRUNCATE, DROP, or UPDATE commands. (They should all be INSERT unless the script is setup to empty the db first or replace existing entries)

Comment: Trying to search at the moment but the database is so big it seems to take forever. Do you have Skype?

Comment: If you want, try creating a new empty database and import it into that one to see what it does. Yes I have Skype, just don't have it installed atm.

Comment: I'd need to create a new mysql database in phpmyadmin and then import into that? then I can see if the records are there? but won't show me if they would replace or remove the new ones?

Comment: that wouldn't affect or break anything else?

Comment: Nope, as long as it's restricted to that one DB. Before you run it, check if your script starts with a line something like "USE DBNAME" where DBNAME is the name of the existing database

Comment: ok, I'll try... although not really sure what I am doing. To import it, that's in phpmyadmin? or restore database in cpanel?

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin. However seeing as you have cPanel you are most likely on a shared or managed server right? If so, your hosting company should be able to assist you better

Comment: They don't seem very useful unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you restore a DB backup you will get your shop to the exactly the same state as it was at the moment of backup creation.

So, yes, it will erase the last 24hrs of work and any new products you added after the DB backup creation.

This concerns only the DB changes you did during that time - new orders, products, customers, Magento settings you may have tweaked. Any PHP/HTML-CSS code changes you did will still remain intact.